# Polyhedral graphs from consecutive power distances

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, graph-theory

Raise a real value to powers 0 to $n-1$ for $n$ different lengths. Build a polyhedral graph from those lengths, none missing or repeated.

I have found 4 solutions, all wheel graphs. Are there any others? In the images below, the number indicates the power.  The 0 edge has length $a^0=1$.

[image: consecutive power graphs]

These use the 2nd real values of the following polynomials:
$$x^6-x^2-1,\\ x^8-x^2-1, \\x^{12}+x^8-x^4-x^2-1, \\6 x^{16}+x^{15}-3 x^{14}-2 x^{13}-3 x^{11}+8 x^{10}-2 x^9-x^8-6 x^7-x^6+x^4-4 x^3-4 x^2+2 x+6$$

Are there any other solutions?

Comment: I suppose you're not allowing $a=1$, where any polyhedron with all edge lengths equal works.

Comment: Nope, has to be different lengths.

Comment: Seems like you have some "secret formula" in generating these graphs ;). Are you claiming that there are only 4 possible wheel graphs?

Comment: Can you explain why it's the 2nd real value, as opposed to the 1st (or the 3rd or ...), that seems to yield these graphs?

Comment: At first I thought that an action of the Galois group of each polynomial would turn the associated graph into a different graph of a similar kind. But then I realized that the embedding of the graph into the plane may involve points whose coordinates do not belong to the number field generated by the roots of the polynomial. Still, I can't help wondering if there's a "Galois story" here.

Comment: 2nd real value --- just a coincidence.  These may be the only wheel graphs of this type where all triangles are internally similar.  I found another - swap 6 and 7 in the first graph.  The polynomial root is nasty.

Comment: -4 + 4 x^2 - 5 x^4 + 6 x^6 - 9 x^8 + 15 x^10 - 3 x^12 + 15 x^14 - 
 7 x^16 + 16 x^18 - 9 x^20 + 10 x^22 - 10 x^24 + 4 x^26 - 5 x^28 + 
 2 x^30 - 4 x^32 + 2 x^34 - x^36 + x^38 -- fifth real root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Nautilus Graphs

There appear to be an infinite series of "Nautilus" wheel-graphs from order n=8 onward with an increasing number of "chambers". The choice of the name "Nautilus" becomes apparent for largish n. Eg:

[image: Nautilus Graph n=22]

I've generated Nautiluses up to order n=52, but higher orders require finding the root of polynomials of progressively higher degrees. I presume the series to be unbounded, but have not proven this. Inspiration for looking at these "Nautilus" graphs came from a Facebook post of an order n=14 graph by Ed Pegg.

### Tetrahedral Graphs

If I've not made a mistake, there are six distinct, non-degenerate configurations for the tetrahedral graph:

[image: Tetra r=0.790406]
[image: Tetra r=0.821894]
[image: Tetra r=0.832979]
[image: Tetra r=0.836909]
[image: Tetra r=0.840896]
[image: Tetra r=0.844069]

Note that none of these conform to the "Nautilus" edge pattern.

Comment: Very nice. I suppose that for any x and number of segments you can simply build the nautilus graph apart from the longest edge. You then have to choose x such that the missing edge is exactly the right length. Intuitively it seems to me that this will always be possible, as varying x changes the angle between the longest and shortest spokes. What is the smallest nautilus graph that works, i.e. the least number of spokes?

Comment: Order 5 (3 "spokes"), if you allow degenerate "flat" trianges; order 7 (4 "spokes"), otherwise. See https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.10215546904009490.1073741841.1346415199&type=3 for images for orders 5 thru 51.